# Need help in Installing Tide SDK in Linux

Tags: tidesdk

I was very excited when I came to know about Tide yesterday.But I am frustrated now after struggling with mere installation for more than 24 hours now.

I downloaded `TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86.zip` but it had not any executables and after reading on a blog I found that you have to download `TiDev Community` which works as IDE and I downloaded that too.

Now I have two problems.

**1)** I extracted TiDev community on my Desktop and when I run installer in terminal I got this

```
INTRUDER installer # ./installer

(process:2670): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.0/./glib/goption.c:2175: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (32) on option of arg-type 4 in entry (null):updatefile

(process:2670): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.0/./glib/goption.c:2175: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (32) on option of arg-type 1 in entry (null):type

(process:2670): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.0/./glib/goption.c:2175: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (32) on option of arg-type 0 in entry (null):sudo

(process:2670): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.34.0/./glib/goption.c:2175: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (32) on option of arg-type 5 in entry (null):
```

plus this as popup

```
The installer was not given any information to continue.
```

**2)** If `TiDev Community` installs successfully, then what was the use of that `TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86.zip` package?

[PS:Please don't suggest the method of building it online as y device has no internet connection.I have to it offline]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to 'install' anything. I just downloaded [TideSDK SDK](https://github.com/downloads/TideSDK/TideSDK/TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-linux-x86.zip) and the [Developer App](https://github.com/downloads/TideSDK/TideSDK/TideSDK-Developer-1.4.2-linux-x86.tgz) (maybe you use 64bit...then choose these).

Then you must extract the SDK into your users folder: `~/.tidesdk`. After that you have a `sdk` folder in there. The Developer can be extracted whereever you want. You don't need to execute the installer. Just execute `TideSDK Developer`.

PS:

The TiDev Developer app is replaced by the Developer App that you can download from the tidesdk website.